# Trying to access the Twitter API returns AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'oauth'

Tags: twitter, oauth, python-twitter

Why does the following error occur when I attempt to access the Twitter API?

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        17 
>        18 
>   ---> 19 auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(access_token_key,access_token_secret,consumer_key,consumer_secret)
>        20 #twitter = twitter.Twitter(auth=twitter.oauth.OAuth(access_token_key,access_token_secret,consumer_key,consumer_secret))
>        21 twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'oauth'

My code:

```
import twitter
#from twitter import *
#from twitter import oauth

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret =''
access_token_key = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(access_token_key,access_token_secret,consumer_key,consumer_secret)
#twitter = twitter.Twitter(auth=twitter.oauth.OAuth(access_token_key,access_token_secret,consumer_key,consumer_secret))
twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)

print twitter
```

Answer (score 0):

I would read their [documentation](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter) carefully.

From the link I mentioned:

```
from twitter import *

t = Twitter(
    auth=OAuth(token, token_key, con_secret, con_secret_key))
```

So you see that `auth=OAuth` not `auth=oauth.OAuth`

In your case you have `import twitter`, the only difference that's there is you'll need to add `twitter` before each attribute as you have done, but you still don't need `oauth`

```
import twitter 

t = twitter.Twitter(
    auth=twitter.OAuth(token, token_key, con_secret, con_secret_key))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, also ensure that you have done -

```
pip install oauth
```